# Pivoting with missing values

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pivot, pyspark

I have a `DataFrame` with the following simple `schema`:

```
root
 |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I was trying to see the `sum` of amounts per day and per hour, some like:

```
+---+--------+--------+ ... +--------+
|day|       0|       1|     |      23|
+---+--------+--------+ ... +--------+
|148|   306.0|   106.0|     |     0.0|
|243|  1906.0|    50.0|     |     1.0|
| 31|   866.0|   100.0|     |     0.0|
+---+--------+--------+ ... +--------+
```

Well, first I added a column `hour` and then I grouped by day, and pivoted by hour. However, I got an exception, which perhaps is related to missing sales for some hours. This is what I'm trying to fix but I haven't realized how.

```
(df.withColumn("hour", hour("date"))
    .groupBy(dayofyear("date").alias("day"))
    .pivot("hour")
    .sum("amount").show())
```

An excerpt of the exception.

> AnalysisException: u'resolved attribute(s) date#3972 missing from
>   day#5367,hour#5354,sum(amount)#5437 in operator !Aggregate
>   [dayofyear(cast(date#3972 as date))], [dayofyear(cast(date#3972 as
>   date)) AS day#5367, pivotfirst(hour#5354, sum(amount)#5437, 0, 1, 2,
>   3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
>   22, 23, 0, 0) AS __pivot_sum(amount) AS sum(amount)#5487];'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unresolved `day` column. You can create it outside `groupBy` clause to address that:

```
df = (sc
         .parallelize([
             (1.0, "2016-03-30 01:00:00"), (30.2, "2015-01-02 03:00:02")])
        .toDF(["amount", "Date"])
        .withColumn("Date", col("Date").cast("timestamp"))
        .withColumn("hour", hour("date")))

with_day = df.withColumn("day", dayofyear("Date"))
with_day.groupBy("day").pivot("hour", range(0, 24)).sum("amount")
```

`values` argument for `pivot` is optional but advisable.